# How to prevent wild card glob expansion for occurring for my command like scp does?

Tags: wildcard, scp, glob, expansion

I wish for my application to accept an file specification argument literally, without wildcard expansion.  This is because the directory from which my command is being run is not the directory (or machine) where the glob expansion should be performed.  I believe the scp somehow manages to do this, but I am at a loss to replicate that in my tool other than quoting the argument, but somehow scp doesn't require quoting, so I would like to do likewise.

How can I prevent wildcard expansion for my command line argument like scp does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what shell are you using? In bash, you can use `set -o noglob`. Otherwise, please provide more information to the problem definition.